# Passing an array as thread's argument

Tags: c

I have some issues with my code. I need to pass an int array to a thread witch will calculate the ^2 of every int of the array.
My code:

```
#include <pthread.h> //etc.

#define SIZE 1024
static void * function_thread(void *arg){

  int *loc = (int *)arg;  
  // i tried also int loc[SIZE] = (int *)arg; but won' compile ion' t know  why 
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    loc[i] = loc[i] * loc[i];
    // tried also loc[i] = (*(int *)arg) * (*(int *)arg); 
    printf("loc[%d]^2 = %d\n",i, loc[i]);
  }
  return (void *)loc;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int x[SIZE];
    void  (*res[SIZE]);
    int y[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        x[i] = i;
     }
     pthread_t thread_1;
     pthread_create(&thread_1,NULL,function_thread,x);

     pthread_join(thread_1, &res);

     for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        y[i] =  res[i];
      }
}
```

So i have few questions:

1. There is something wrong already in the thread function? is giving me loc[i] = 0 for each i.What's the problem?
2. why the initialization of *int loc[SIZE] = (int * )arg; doesnìt work?
3. I have seen that

   int x;
     int * result;
     ...
     pthread_join(someThread, &result);
     x = result + result;

this works.But why? isn't  x and result types different?

Thanks you in advice and wish you a good day!

Comment: With `void  (*res[SIZE])` you declare that `res` is an array of `SIZE` pointers to `void`. What it really should be is exactly what `loc` is inside the thread function: A pointer to `int` (`int *res`). Then you can use it just like any other array or pointer, and don't need the copying. In fact, since the thread returns the pointer it receives, you don't need `res` (or `y`) at all, all changes the thread makes is already in `x`.

Comment: The code can't compile - check that you have posted the correct code!

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/9zSp6h) once I remove the spurious line `loc[i]` which causes compilation to fail.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude it works, but when add another thread to calculate x^3 and y = res1 + res2 i have strange number. Is that a problem of sync?

Comment: @Racma, you said you are creating two threads from which you store the result arrays in two different pointers (res1 and res2). However are you passing the same x array pointer to both threads as input argument? If that is the case both thread would access concurrently to the same memory area.

Comment: @matteomartelli yeah i solve it with declaring 3 more arrays. The problem was that every thread was changing the array x itself and was not treating a local copy. newbie mistake...thanks anyway!